# db2oledb Performance single vs multi threaded

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange

Having an issue with DB2OLEDB performance, using sql server 2017 performing a data load from IBM i 7.3 .

The client is a VMware VM, network settings seem ok and have been tweaked up to the best of my ability (vmxnet3 driver 1.8).  Load from other VMs or from www flies at over 100mbits.

Troubleshooting so far:
DB2OLEDB (Microsoft) performs substantially faster (3-5x) than IBMDASQL.
Setting I/O Affinity mask to one core doubles performance, but additional cores have no impact.
RSS is on.
DB2OLEDB inprocess on/off has no effect on throughput but off introduces substantial spool up time at the beginning of each query.

Performance currently around 15 mbit.  Same table from another SQL server (cached) loads about 3x faster at 50mbit+ (different provider obviously).

Interestingly, enabling rowcache spikes network throughput at the beginning to 100-150mbits.  I.e. I'm inferring that there is plenty of network bandwidth available.

Finally, we are using in-memory table as destination in order to eliminate disk i/o as a culprit.

Cpu is burning up one core and the remaining are at ~20% ish.

Any thoughts?

I suspect that DB2OLEDB driver or some part of COM is the bottleneck at this point.

edit: @MandyShaw (too long for comment) Windows Side.  IBM i never breaks 1% for my particular workload and it generaly runs 25%-50% load depending on TOD.  SQL statements are varied.  Everything from straight four part query to 7 table snowflake as a passthrough.  One interesting thing: throughput  (network) varies based on row length.  Wider tables appear to pump at roughly the same row rate as thinner tables.  This is true for both the IBM and Microsoft driver.  Reducing network latency had a great impact on performance (see RSC issues with Vmxnet3 driver 1.6.6.0).  If I understand correctly the OLEDB drivers fetch one row at a time (except possibly when loading the rowset cache).

In other words, for every row we're issuing a request from SQL server to COM/OLEDB driver to Supervisor Network Driver, to Hypervisor Network driver, to physical NIC, through fiber and landing at the IBM i.  Then back again.  We have successfully been able to multiplex large table loads using the service broker (but this is impractical for most applications). This, as well as other metrics, suggests that the IBM i has plenty of cpu and bandwidth to spare.  The fiber fabric is mostly idle, we've tuned the bejeezus out of the hypervisor (VMware) and the supervisor (tcp/ip stack) as well as the SQL server itself.

This is why I'm looking at the COM/OLEDB provider for answers.  Something in this model seems to stink.  It's either not configured properly or simply doesn't support multiple threads of execution.

I'm also willing to accept that it's something in SQL server, but for the life of me I can't find a way to make a linked server query run multi-threaded using any combination of configuration, options or hints.  Again, it may just not be possible by design.

At this point in time, the few known leads that I have involve (1) tuning network interrupt request coalescing and frequency to minimize interrupts to the OLEDB driver thread and (2) throwing the HIS gateway on a consumer x86 box with a high single core frequency (5ghz) in order to maximize single threaded performance.

These are both shitty options.

If you've got something particular in mind with the EBCIDIC/ASCII conversion performance, I'd be happy to try it and report back.  Shoot me a link/info.

Comment: I am inclined to suspect EBCDIC-ASCII conversion as one possible villain here.  What does your SQL statement look like? Also, is your core CPU usage (as quoted) on the Windows side or the IBM i side?

Comment: @MandyShaw Answer too long for comment, please see edit.

Comment: Re EBCDIC/ASCII, I have no way of telling whether it will make a material difference, but alphanumeric IBM i data will be stored in EBCDIC and it will need converting to ASCII to go into SQL Server, so something, somewhere, will be spending CPU cycles doing that. I know your IBM i box is doing ok performance wise but I'd still get your IBM i DBA to look at the performance from that side - another possibility is that the table there has a lot of deleted records, which could also have shockingly bad effects on the performance of this sort of activity.

Comment: @MandyShaw by default I'm also the IBM i DBA.  So far we've looked through DRDA/DDM configuration.  Set up a separate partition for BI jobs with pretty much uncapped memory, high thread limit, high priority etc, etc.  Query execution time on the IBM is trivial, with the heaviest joins taking about 10 seconds to execute.  Monitoring the performance stats on the IBM suggests that the QZDASOINIT jobs sitting idle and waiting on network I/O.  I'm actually inferring that the decreased performance of the IBMDASQL driver is due to the fact that it's translating locally rather than on the IBM i.

Comment: That sounds right, and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzaik/rzaikoledbprovider.htm says that's where it's happening. I'd be tempted to try it with translation switched off (you should be able to configure that on the IBMDASQL connection) - you'll get nonsense (well, EBCDIC) in SQL Server, but you'll be able to rule this in or out as a cause of performance issues.

Comment: N.B. I don't think you are using the DDM/DRDA driver or configuration at all, you will be using the Database Host Server (that is what QZDASOINIT jobs are listeners for). If there is a DB2 Connect OLE DB driver (I don't know, sorry) and you have the right sort of DB2 Connect licence, you /could/ try that, i.e. talk to DRDA, though since the vast majority of IBM i sites go down the other route I suspect that's where the development and performance dollars will have gone.

Comment: P.S. You might check the connection pooling parameters re QZDASOINIT if you haven't done so already and if they're remotely relevant to your setup, sorry can't remember where those are configured.